# Storing strings which are enterd using spaces

Tags: c, string

How can i Store strings which are inputted using spaces.
For eg: Strings entered using newline can be stored using for loop and then stored to array, Similarly how to store strings which are entered as a single line, but with spaces

Comment: You can use functions fgets and strtok.

Comment: `scanf("%s", str)` in a loop?

Comment: After entering I want to store each word into an array.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you don't need help if you already know what you're doing (e.g. you think `stdin` isn't the console, or isn't a `FILE *`, and thus anything that operates on `FILE *` won't help you)... right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fscanf`'s `%s` format directive. It has a field width if you're interested in avoiding buffer overflows (which you should be), for example `char foo[128]; int x = fscanf(stdin, "%127s", foo);`... Don't forget to check `x`.

There's some error checking that needs to occur after reading such a fixed width field. If `fscanf` reads the maximum number of characters, it's required to stop reading... There's a good chance that some non-space characters might be left on the stream, which should be discarded using something like: `fscanf(stdin, "%*[^ \n]");`. You might also want to let the user know that their input has been truncated.

Alternatively, if you'd like to read *really large words of an unknown length* you could use this function I wrote:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *get_dynamic_word(FILE *f) {
    size_t bytes_read = 0;
    char *bytes = NULL;
    int c;
    do {
        c = fgetc(f);
    } while (c >= 0 && isspace(c));
    do {
        if ((bytes_read & (bytes_read + 1)) == 0) {
            void *temp = realloc(bytes, bytes_read * 2 + 1);
            if (temp == NULL) {
                free(bytes);
                return NULL;
            }
            bytes = temp;
        }

        bytes[bytes_read] = c >= 0 && !isspace(c)
                          ? c
                          : '\0';
        c = fgetc(f);
    } while (bytes[bytes_read++]);
    if (c >= 0) {
        ungetc(c, f);
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

Example: `char *foo = get_dynamic_word(stdin);` Don't forget to `free(foo);`...

An example assigning words to an array? No problemo:

```
char *bar[42] = { 0 }
bar[0] = get_dynamic_word(stdin);
bar[1] = get_dynamic_word(stdin);
/* ... */
```

Don't forget to `free(bar[0]); free(bar[1]); /* ... */`

Comment: I am trying to read output from console. Not from file.

Comment: @TomJMuthirenthi: So just pass in `stdin`.

Comment: `stdin` (*"the console"*) is a `FILE *`, @TomJMuthirenthi